# Inserting an ArrayList of String Arraylists as records into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

I'm doing a project which will read the contents of every cell of row of an Excel spreadsheet and store all of this information in an ArrayList of String ArrayLists, before inserting all of these rows as records into a MySQL database.

I have a method which extracts this data fine, and returns the full ArrayList of String ArrayLists. The problem I am having is trying to insert these String ArrayLists as records into the SQL database. I'm getting an index out of bounds exception at run time.

Could anyone please try to explain where it is I am going wrong? I think there is some fundemental flaw in my understanding of ArrayLists/looping/JDBC/all of the previous.

```
public void insertData(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> l) {
    try {

        String insert = "INSERT INTO 1person (ModuleNumber, ModuleTitle, School, ModuleCoordinator, NumberOfStudents, ExamCW, Courses, Blankety, Blank) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(insert);

        for (ArrayList<String> ar1 : l) {
            //for(int i = 0; i < ar1.size(); i ++){
            //ps.setString(i+1, ar1.get(i)
            ps.setString(1, ar1.get(0).toString());
            ps.setString(2, ar1.get(1).toString());
            ps.setString(3, ar1.get(2).toString());
            ps.setString(4, ar1.get(3).toString());
            ps.setString(5, ar1.get(4).toString());
            ps.setString(6, ar1.get(5).toString());
            ps.setString(7, ar1.get(6).toString());
            ps.setString(8, ar1.get(7).toString());
            ps.setString(9, ar1.get(8).toString());
            //}

        }
        ps.execute();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

> returns: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8

Comment: Your list size `8` but you are trying to retrieving `9` item from the list as `ar1.get(8)`.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this yet?

Comment: Yes Jan, thank you. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have only 8 values where you should have 9 (you try to insert 9 values!)

Just as well you only call `execute()` once - but you should either call it per line of insert (and call `executeUpdate()` in case of `INSERT` or `UPDATE`) or you could batch your inserts and then call `executeBatch()`.

Try it like this:

```
for (ArrayList<String> ar1 : l) {
   if(line.size() != 9) {      
     System.out.println("This line only had "+line.size()+" elements - supposed to contain 9");
     for(String item : ar1) {
        //Show for finding the error
        System.out.println("- " + item);
     }
   } else {
      for(int i = 0; i <9; ++i) {
        ps.setString(i+1, ar1.get(i));
      }
      //Mark this line to be added
      ps.addBatch();
   }     
}
int[] result = ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, that's cleared things up for me. Works perfectly now! Many thnaks